# Get logged-in user in html page with C# code and without opening in VS?

Tags: iis, windows-identity

We have a pure html page running in our IIS, and we would like to know what logged-in users are accessing the page. By "logged-in" users I mean a user that looged on to our intranet in their Windows machine.

It seems that I can't retrieve this information with javascript or html, so I was considering using `.net` for this, something like the following:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Is it possible to add server-side code to this HTML page without having to go to `Visual Studio` to create a solution or project?

I just don't want to have to "convert" this `.HTML` into an `.ASPX` just for one line of code. These html pages have tons of javascript charts, and I know something will break if I open it in VS.

Comment: you could use iis request logging.

Comment: Why was it downvoted?

Comment: A `.html` file is not going to be touched by your server. It's just a file and it will be served to the browser as such. Putting any code in it that is meant to be executed server-side will fail because the server won't even bother parsing it. You'll have to name the file with an `.aspx` extension in order for the server to take a look at it. Consider checking out [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_first_example.htm) which has a bare bones `aspx` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't run server code in HTML.

You can do the following:

1. Create ASPX file which runs on the server.

#### currentcontext.aspx

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<script language="CS" runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
      Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    } 
</script>
```

2. Add iframe to the html page which needs to show the current context.

#### yourfile.html

```
<iframe src="currentcontext.aspx"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you, never thought of that. Worked well.

Comment: It is recommended to use `Page.User`. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent` is something else.